# Why was I banned?

Tags: support, post-ban

I have asked one question on this site that received one answer. The question was marked as a possible dupe (I don't dispute that).

The question: [force programs and connections to use a proxy server in windows?](https://superuser.com/q/430734/137161)

Anyway, I wanted to ask another question today... and I cannot! I get the

> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

Except I don't see a real reason for the ban, and I would like to ask a question – not sit and upvote or add comments or something for a while.

Is it just because I'm not that active on this site, or… did I do something?

Maybe I have asked other, more terrible questions, or given just the worst answers, but my account isn't showing this, hence this question!

Answer (score 10):

The question ban that is imposed on your account basically stems from three of your four questions being deleted. Also, three of four questions are closed. You have not received a single upvote, and one deleted question scores at -4. Whether you're actively participating or not does not matter here—except for the fact that downvoted and closed questions will be deleted after some time.

Unfortunately, this means you'll have to work a little harder towards getting back the privilege to ask questions.

We can only help you by undeleting posts that are worth improving. While two of your deleted questions are unsalvageable (since they're out of scope for SU), I undeleted [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/476763/how-do-i-make-the-pc-zune-download-a-movie-not-stream-it) for you. There is nothing else we can do, sorry.

At this point, I'd suggest you try and:

- Provide good contributions in forms of answers.
- Thoroughly check out our site's scope before posting any more questions.
- If you post, please capitalize the "I" properly (not "i"). While it seems minor, this *does* matter.

Comment: gah! not putting in a capital 'i' is a stylistic choice i made! Now SE is hitting my style? What next, my clogs are going to get me banned too? What about the hawaiian?

Comment: @bharal in order to curate high-quality content, Stack Exchange has minimum quality requirements for posts. Using proper grammar is one of those requirements. Choosing not to capitalize _I_ is not a stylistic choice, it's incorrect English.

Comment: While the interpretation of English grammar is definitely up to you, please don't forget that this site has a large audience, and most visitors will find your posts harder to read if they—at least to some degree—don't adhere to proper grammar. If you find your posts constantly being edited by others, please think about sacrificing your "stylistic choice" for the benefit of your readers. Even more important than anyone's personal opinion about capitalization is the fact that the Stack Exchange engine simply won't let you post if there are obvious signs of poor formatting. Hope you understand.

Comment: sigh. Also, i'm pretty sure that *i* might have deleted those questions - at least I am 99% sure i deleted the one that you just  undeleted, slhck, because I realised it Wasn't Great. If i ask a question and then solve it right afterwards, realising what i was trying was Just Wrong, am i just meant to let it... stay? Deleting seems to land me in hot water

Comment: @bharal You didn't delete any of your questions yourself. They were auto-deleted due to their age/state. If you ask a question and solve it right afterwards, the best thing you can do is to actually put your answer below the question. This way, others with the same problem will find your solution. A win-win situation. But yeah, with regard to automatic bans, the amount of deleted posts definitely plays a large role.