# Did I do such low-quality questions? Please review my ban

Tags: discussion, support, post-ban

Now I want to ask about a connection problem and I find my account banned from asking questions.

What did I do to get this? Were my questions out of scope? If so, why no one says which site is the appropiate to ask them? I didn't recieve any feedback from moderators.

Only one question got negative votes, and still none of them aren't closed. Also I did an answer in which got upvoted twice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why was I banned?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6945/why-was-i-banned)

Comment: Question bans are automated, so the mods could not have told you anything. Do you have any deleted questions?

Comment: I remember deleting one question, but it happened a couple of months ago.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Was my possible duplicate a viable duplicate in your opinion?

Comment: This is one of those cases where I'd rather not VTC as dupe, personally, simply cause circumstances may differ

Comment: @JourneymanGeek If I had enough rep, I would wait for an answer before voting to close.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have two deleted questions, [one heavily downvoted](https://superuser.com/questions/643059/it-is-convenient-to-leave-uac-activated-on-windows-7). From looking over your profile, this does seem like a borderline case. Meaning, you're not in too deep.

If you read through [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) carefully, you will find a couple of tips for getting unbanned, including:

> The only way for the ban to be lifted is by contributing positively to the site in other ways. Before you do anything else, fix your existing posts!

So you could edit your existing questions to improve them, or post helpful answers, or suggest edits to improve others' posts. I'm sure that a little positive participation would get you back on track.

Comment: Uh? "We are no longer accepting answers from this account" -> "post helpful answers"?

Comment: @Olli There are separate bans for questions and answers. You can be banned from asking, but that doesn't stop you from contributing through answers. The OP was banned from asking, hence the suggestion to post helpful answers.

Comment: Ah, my bad. That makes sense.